# Flutter UI - Container Border Margin interface Issue

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, containers, border

I've been trying to work on my ecommerce homepage, as you can see from the screenshot I'm trying to fix the categories icon position in my Homescreen
though it seem  to be stable on Android switching to iOS screen it becomes unstable making unclickable.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong ?

Goal vs reality

[image: Goal]   [image: Screenshot]

**HomeScreen**

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  var height = Get.height;
  var width = Get.width;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding:
              EdgeInsets.only(top: 40, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 120,
                    width: 365,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        boxShadow: const [
                          BoxShadow(
                              color: Colors.grey,
                              blurRadius: 2.0,
                              offset: Offset(2.0, 2.0))
                        ]),
                    child: CategoriesGrid(
                      height: height,
                      width: width,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**CategoriesGrid**

```
class CategoriesGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  const CategoriesGrid({
    Key key,
    this.height,
    this.width,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final double height;
  final double width;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: height * 0.16,
      width: width,
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: width * 0.02),
        child: Center(
          child: GridView.builder(
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 4),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                    child: InkWell(
                      child: CategoryWidget(
                        height: height,
                        width: width,
                        onTap: () {
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  itemCount: 4,
                ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget CategoryWidget(
    {double height,
    double width,
    Function() onTap}) {
  return InkWell(
    onTap: onTap,
    child: Container(
      height: height * 0.07,
      width: width * 0.1,
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Image.asset(
            imagePath,
            height: height * 0.05,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: height * 0.01,
          ),
          Text(
            '$titleText',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, took some effort I've added  `Padding` Before calling `CategoriesGrid` and removed the `Container`

Here's the updated code

**HomeScreen**

```
                 Container(
                      height: height/8,
                      width: 365,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                blurRadius: 2.0,
                                offset: Offset(2.0, 2.0))
                          ]),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding:  EdgeInsets.only(top:Get.height/34),
                        child: CategoriesGrid(
                          height: height,
                          width: width,
                          internetAvailable:
                          homePageController.internetAvailable,
                          listOfTitles: homePageController.listOfTitles,
                          listOfCategoryImages:
                          homePageController.listOfCategoryImages,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

**CategoriesGrid**

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: width * 0.02),
  child: GridView.builder(
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    gridDelegate:
        SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 4),
    itemBuilder: (context, index) => InkWell(
      child: CategoryWidget(
        titleText: listOfTitles[index],
        imagePath: listOfCategoryImages[index],
        onTap: () {
          Get.to(() => OffersList(
                index: index,
              ));
        },
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try Flexible - it controls how a child of base flex widgets that are Row, Column, and Flex will fill the space available to it

i.e

```
Flexible(
  fit: FlexFit.tight,
  child: Foo(),
);
```